# React lifecyle methods, to componentWillReceiveProps or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a collapsible `OrgChart` component with React.

I'm not sure how to use the lifecycle methods to re-render the Edges (SVG path that links 2 nodes), based on user interactions. I would like to know if there is a better approach than using `componentWillReceiveProps` (or since it's going to be obsolete soon, `componentDidUpdate` and/or `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead) for this case

The Edges should only be painted once all the nodes have been painted first. However in my code, each `Node` paints its incoming Edge. This, because the HTML code that makes the chart collapsible using `CSS` requires `Node` and its `Edge` under the same `div`:

```
NodeContainer = (props) => 
  <div className='nodeContainer'>
    <Node />
    <Edge />
  </div>
```

My `OrgChart` component has 3 main components:

- `Chart.tsx`: receives a `graph` object props that contains the list of nodes and edges, and uses it to build the chart. Also receives a few other props such as call back functions for chart or node manipulation (eg: `onNodeSelected(id)`, `onChartMoved()`)
- `Node.tsx`: paints both the Node and its incoming svg Edge.
- `Edge.tsx`: paints the SVG Edge

So far, I was thinking of organizing my code this way:

**Chart.tsx**

```
// augmentedGraph will have extra data for each node and edge.
// For example: the node coordinates, isCollapsed. The coordinates are purely a UI concern, hence why my incoming graph props should not contain the info.
class Chart extends Component {
  state = { augmentedGraph: this.props.graph }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

    if (this.props.graph.nodes.length !== prevProps.graph.nodes.length 
      || this.state.augmentedGraph !== prevState.augmentedGraph){

      // clone this.props.graph into this.state.augmentedGraph
      // and re-calculates all edges and nodes coordinates to add those properties to this.state.augmentedGraph
      ...

    }
  }

  // Will send callback function props to each Node (onNodeMoved, etc.), that will fire below method
  userModifiedChartHandler() {
    // re-calculates all edges and nodes coordinates and updates this.state.augmentedGraph
  }

  // recursively builds the chart html structure with Nodes and Edges.
  buildChart(node) {
    return ...
  }

  render() {
    const rootNode = this.state.augmentedGraph.nodes.root
    const chart = buildChart(rootNode)
    return ({chart})
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `buildChart`?

Comment: What is your goal behind using the lifecycle methods as opposed to calculating everything in the `render` method? Performance? If so, couldn't you just use memoization as described in the React docs?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization

Comment: @enguerran `buildChart` is a function that recursively create the JSX code that builds the chart. I did not represent it here because it's irrelevant to my issue.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth my `Chart` component receives a `graph` props containing arrays of `node` and `edge` that don't have any coordinate data. The only time the `graph` props would trigger a re-render, is when users change its structure (delete, create, move nodes). To manage the other user interactions (such as collapse, move the chart, zoom, etc.), I need to keep coordinates for each nodes and edges in the `Chart.tsx`'s `state`. Hence, I need to use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to check if user did something. So it's not only for performance, but just for my code to work it seems.

Comment: You are aware that changes to the state also perform a rendering? So far I haven't heard anything that speaks against using memoization

Comment: A classical react lifecycle is as follow: change props of the used component → run render of the component. You ain't need anything else: if `this.props` changes, the `render` method is called, if it results to a different tree, the virtual DOM algorithm will render it in the DOM rendered in your browser.

Comment: When users do something, it is through an event you have to listen to and the event handler can call `setState` as @DanielHilgarth says.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple [memoization approach](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization):

```
calculateCoordinates = memoize((nodesLength, graph) => { your recalculation code })

render() {
    const augmentedGraph = this.augmentGraph(this.props.graph.nodes.length, this.props.graph);
    return {buildChart(rootNode, augmentedGraph)};
}
```

Obviously, there is a lot of detail missing in your question. For example, I am missing the connection between `augmentedGraph` and `rootNode`.
In general, the memoization approach is used to remove state from the component, in this case, the augmented graph.
The parameters to the lambda that is passed to `memoize` are the keys on which you want to decide whether the input data has changed and you need to re-execute your calculation code.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I've added the details about `rootNode`. I'll see what I can do with `memoization` and come back to you, as I am pretty much a beginner and it takes time for me. Mainly, I want to know if it makes sense to make `Chart.tsx` stateful with `augmentedGraph` being based on `this.props.graph` with extra nodes and edges coordinates, and keeping `augmentedGraph` in sync with `this.props.graph` using `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: So, user interactions on the graph - like onNodeMove - will change `augmentedGraph`? In other words, if `props.graph` changes, the changes made to `augmentedGraph` will be lost?

Comment: yes: interactions like onMoveNode will change `augmentedGraph`. In my mind, `this.props.graph`, coming from a server, should only care about user interactions that create, delete or change a node's parent. Any other interactions, such as onNodeMove, onNodeCollapse, etc. should be taken care of in `Chart.tsx`. The changes made to `augmentedGraph` should not be lost. I'd merge both, as `augmentedGraph` is basicall = `this.props.graph`, but inside, instead of having `node: {id: 1, title: 'Node 1' }`, it will add `node: {id: 1, title: 'Node 1', x: 145, y: 243}`

Comment: I would keep these separate. I would have a hash map of coordinates with the id as the key

Comment: And this leads back to the memoization technique: The augmentedGraph can always be calculated from `props.graph` and `state.coordinates`.

Comment: I'll try the memoization, and will come back to you. Thank you for that!

Comment: Great. Note that `memoize-one` - what is used in the article I linked - only performs a shallow copy of the input parameters.

Comment: It always feel like peeling an onion when you're a beginner: I'm not sure what are the implications of a shallow copy in my case. Or should I just use another memoization library?

Comment: I am sorry. I meant: shallow *comparison*. So it does a shallow comparison of the previously known input parameters to the newly passed ones. If they differ, it will re-calculate. However, because its a shallow comparison, it will not detect changes in child objects.